# PHP loop - creating a table using a loop and giving it headers

Tags: php, html, loops, while-loop, html-table

I am a few stages further in learning PHP but I have come to another annoying pit stop. I have a really simple bit of code that retrieves book items from my database. I am displaying them in an html table however because it is a loop, if I use the th tags for table header I get a header above every single data item!

Here is my code extract: (as you can see I have put my th tags as comments as that doesn't work)

```
<table border="0">
<br />
<?php
$count = 0;
while ($count < $numrow)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($results);
    extract($row);

    echo "<tr>";

    //echo "<tr>";
    //echo "<th>";
    //echo "Book Title";
    //echo "</th>";
    //echo "<th>";
    //echo "Book Author";
    //echo "</th>";
    //echo "<th>";
    //echo "Book Publisher";
    //echo "</th>";
    //echo "<th>";
    //echo "Book ISBN";
    //echo "</th>";
    //echo "</tr>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href='addtolist.php?     bookname=".$bookname."&bookauthor=".$bookauthor."&bookpub=".$bookpub."&bookisbn=".$bookisbn."'>[+]</a>";

    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $bookname;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $bookauthor;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $bookpub;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $bookisbn;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href='deletecd.php?bookname=".$bookname."'>Delete</a>";
        echo "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";

    $count = $count + 1;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move those `echo`s out of your loop. Also, you shouldn't have a `<br />` directly inside of a `<table>` tag.

Comment: I did notice as soon as I posted question, will remove br.. Thank you for response, will tick your answer as soon as it allows me too!many thanks [=

Comment: That's how it usually happens! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Move your table header code outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

IDIOT! Sorry guys....

Needed to put the th tags outside of the loop.... simple I know but easy to miss when your learning!

[=

Comment: I guess knowing the difference between "your" and "you're" would be helpful some for some of us too.

Answer (score 0):

Simply take the header outside the loop, so echo before you begin your loop but *after* the opening`<table>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the headers above the loop:

```
<table border="0">
<tr>
<th>Book Title</th>
<th>Book Author</th>
<th>Book Publisher</th>
<th>Book ISBN</th>
</tr>

    <?php
    $count = 0;
    while ($count < $numrow)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($results);
        extract($row);

    echo "<tr>"

        echo "<td>";
        echo "<a href='addtolist.php?     bookname=".$bookname."&bookauthor=".$bookauthor."&bookpub=".$bookpub."&bookisbn=".$bookisbn."'>[+]</a>";

        echo "</td>";

        echo "<td>";
        echo $bookname;
        echo "</td>";

        echo "<td>";
        echo $bookauthor;
        echo "</td>";

        echo "<td>";
        echo $bookpub;
        echo "</td>";

        echo "<td>";
        echo $bookisbn;
        echo "</td>";

        echo "<td>";
        echo "<a href='deletecd.php?bookname=".$bookname."'>Delete</a>";
            echo "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";

        $count = $count + 1;

    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="0">
<tr>
<th>Book Title</th>
<th>Book Author</th>
<th>Book Publisher</th>
<th>Book ISBN</th>
</tr>
<?php
$count = 0;
while ($count < $numrow)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($results);
    extract($row);

    echo "<tr>";


    echo "<td>";
...
```

What is static, stays static.
Wjat is dynamic, becomes PHP